# My function is returning a list, when it shouldn't be. I check the var values before and after the `return` and I'm stumped

Tags: powershell

I'm making some PS scripts to help automate some tasks I have. In order to run those scripts I need to have signed files. So I went down the road of creating a self-signing cert and I wanted to make the script a bit more robust, if not overdone. I could always go back to the first iteration and move on, but this is so puzzling to me, I need to figure out why it's happening.

the password and hashes don't matter and I'm rotating through hashes with each run. I plan to remove all busted certs once I can get a clean run through this.

console output:

```
certpath: Cert:\\LocalMachine\My\365B361A71F306681B432CE0B9CFCA7327890F47
before exiting makeCert cert[all] 365B361A71F306681B432CE0B9CFCA7327890F47
before exiting makeCert cert[0] 365B361A71F306681B432CE0B9CFCA7327890F47
before exiting makeCert cert[1] 
after exiting makeCert cert[all] C:\selfcert1.pfx 365B361A71F306681B432CE0B9CFCA7327890F47
after exiting makeCert cert[0] C:\selfcert1.pfx
after exiting makeCert cert[1] 365B361A71F306681B432CE0B9CFCA7327890F47
this is cert Cert:\\LocalMachine\My\C:\selfcert1.pfx 365B361A71F306681B432CE0B9CFCA7327890F47
```

```
function makeCert {
    param
    (
        [string] $pass
    )
    write-host "creating cert" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    #generate a new cert, dnsname should be your FQDN
    $cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation $certStore -dnsname "$env:computername.$env:userdnsdomain" -Type CodeSigningCert -FriendlyName "MyCodeSigningCert"
    write-host $cert -ForegroundColor Red
    write-host $cert.Thumbprint -ForegroundColor Red
    $password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $pass -Force -AsPlainText

    #define the certpath and export the pfx file, if it needs to be shared.
    $certPath = "$certStore$($cert.Thumbprint)"
    Export-PfxCertificate -Cert $certPath -FilePath C:\selfcert1.pfx -Password $password -Force
    write-host "cert created" -ForegroundColor Green
    write-host "certpath:"$certPath
    write-host "before exiting makeCert cert[all]"$cert.Thumbprint
    write-host "before exiting makeCert cert[0]"$cert[0].Thumbprint
    write-host "before exiting makeCert cert[1]"$cert[1].Thumbprint
    return ($cert.Thumbprint)
    # return ($cert[0].Thumbprint) referencing the list item with 0 or 1 makes no difference.
    
}

function main {
    param
    (
        [int] $i
    )
    $password = "passw0rd!"
    $certTP = checkCert
    if ($certTP)
    {
        write-host "Cert found"  -ForegroundColor Green
    }
    else
    {
        write-host "No matching code signing cert. Creating new cert" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        write-host "before making cert"$certTP -ForegroundColor Yellow
        $certTP = makeCert -pass $password
        write-host "after exiting makeCert cert[all]"$certTP -ForegroundColor Yellow
        write-host "after exiting makeCert cert[0]"$certTP[0] -ForegroundColor Yellow
        write-host "after exiting makeCert cert[1]"$certTP[1] -ForegroundColor Yellow
        #importCert -pass $password
    }
    if ($i = 1) {
    certSigning -cert "$certStore$certTP"
    }
}


main -i 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well now I feel quite stupid. I figured where-about the issue was coming from within the function, but I didn't resort to saving the Export call to a variable. The moment I did that, the expected value was returned.

A large part of me wants to delete this, but I'd rather not, in hopes that it'll help someone else.

This post is what lead me to the answer: https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/ask_the_experts/f/learn_powershell-12/5412/tip---watch-out-return-values-from-functions-in-power-shell

> So two things to avoid mangled return data from functions
>
> 1. Remember to remove any lines where you have typed variables to se their value
>
> **2. Remeber to assign output from function calls in a function to variables**
>
> As a powershell rookie I've learned this the hard way